# How to pass complex values to Body of a HTTPRequest in a POST method

Tags: azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using `Azure Functions` and I have a third party `API` I want to call. I have the URL to it but it is a `POST` method so I know to use a "post" for `method type` and also I know about the that I can create a `class` and pass the values in there as a `class object`.
But what if the BODY sample they need is more complex. In my case something like this below.
In that case do I still create a `class`? **How** should I model it when it more complex like this?

```
 {
    "familyHierarchy": {
        "familyMembers": {
            "memberIds": ["string"],
            "age": 0,
            "marriageDate": "string"
        },
        "familyGroup": "string"
    },
    "pageSize": 0
}
```

**Also** here is what currently I have for my **method signature** but not sure about `FromBody` that I am asking about

```
[FunctionName("GetFamilyInfo")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> GetFamilyInfo([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "families/")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

Comment: You want to call this 3rd party API from insider your Azure Function and pass the data first to your Azure Function and then the same gets posted to the API. Is this correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes I think so . I just want to write a AZ function that when I call it, it will call their API with the data I am passing in the body request and then gives me result. I have solved the "GET" and Auth etc for another one of their APIs so I am good with "GET" but not sure about this "POST" one

Comment: In that case you don't really need to do anything special I think. When you invoke your Azure Function (I am assuming it is a HTTP triggered one), you pass the data as request body. In the Function code you would retrieve the request body as is and send it to your API. Deserialization into a class is helpful when you want to do something with the request body in your Function code.

Comment: In short, your Azure Function is simply a pass-through which is acting as a proxy for your 3rd party API.

Comment: @GauravMantri  yes

Comment: @GauravMantri would you please provide an example in an answer ? I have posted the request body they need when I call their API from mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't really need to go through the process of deserializing the request body in a class and then serialize it again to send as request body to your API.

Here's the sample code (untested though). It basically reads the request body and passes it to the post request to the 3rd party API. Hopefully it will give you some ideas about how to proceed:

```
[FunctionName("GetFamilyInfo")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> GetFamilyInfo([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "families/")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string requestBody = String.Empty;
    using (StreamReader streamReader =  new  StreamReader(req.Body))
    {
        requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    //Call the 3rd party API and send the request body
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    await client.PostAsync("https://your3rdpartyapi.com", requestBody);
    ...do some more stuff if needed and return proper status code back
}
```

Comment: confused. So I don't have to "somehow" pass the data I what to know about to my AZ function so it can pass it to that API ? I mean even here how do I call my own function to put some values in the request body ? maybe my real question is how do I populate the request body

Comment: Now I’m confused . Can you edit your question and provide more details about your setup and what you want to accomplish?

Comment: see it has a "memberIds" in their request body, I want to be able to pass a list of memberIds to their api through mine and get their response.  So I want a way to populate this memberIds and pass it

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered creating a data class for that request body?

```
public class FamilyHierarchy {

   private FamilyMembers familyMembers;
   private String FamilyGroup;
   
   public FamilyHierarchy(FamilyMembers familyMembers, FamilyGroup familyGroup) {
      
      this.familyMembers = familyMembers;
      this.familyGroup = familyGroup;

}

   private class FamilyMembers {
   
      private String[] memberIds;
      private int age;
      private String marriageDate;

   }

}
```

When you declare the data class and assign its values, you can use the Gson library to convert it to JSON and send that as the request body.

```
FamilyHierarchy familyHierarchy = new FamilyHierarchy()

[... assign values here ...]

Gson gson = new Gson();
String requestBodyJson = gson.toJson(familyHierarchy);
```

Hope this helps!